# Android SignalR libraries

Tags: android, signalr

I need to develop Android app in which i have to use SignalR library.
I have tried but not succeeded as of now.
I have below questions.

1) Is there any standard Library for SignalR in Android?  (I have downloaded from https://github.com/SignalR/java-client .(it supports only on 4.4.2)
2) Is there any other library which supports earlier version of Android os as well?
3) Any tutorial on SignalR with Android will be really helpful.

Comment: What do you mean it only supports 4.4.2? The manifest declares api level 8 as the minimum api level it supports, which is froyo.

Comment: Yeah initially it was not working on API 8. because the version i downloaded has some UI theme related declarations which was supporting Higher versions of Android. I simply removed them and now its working on API 8 too.

Comment: @Vishal could you please share a sample project with working solution.Or explain the steps involved in integrating signalr to native android

Comment: @Hemant - Yes i will share d steps in detail soon. You can start with below flow for setting up Android SignalR CLIENT - 1) download signalR library 2) Import all projects in eclipse as java projects. 3) Android project contains some UI theme related settings which supports higher version of Android removed it. (i.e. remove theme). Further am considering that you have SignalR SERVER ready with you.

Comment: @Vishal i have done the points you have given and i have signalR server ready with me.

Comment: @Hemant - 1) Are you able to debug the sample signalR android app provided in libraries. 2) IF yes what are the results of test cases. 3) If no what exact issue are you facing. I hope you have provided you signal R Hub address in Android app.

Comment: @Vishal Thanks for you help.I have successfully integrated SignalR.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at my signalR client for Android, SignalA.
https://github.com/erizet/SignalA

REad the readme file for instructions how to use it.

Comment: We have succesffully integrated https://github.com/SignalR/java-client for Android 3.0 as well. There was was some UI related stuff in above libraries which forces it to 4.4.2. I have just removed that UI related code and it works. :)

Comment: Hi, Erik, We are looking for some SignalR library for Anroid and coming across your answer here. Is your SignalR library still actively maintained? Is it working latest Android OS?

Comment: Hi @windfly2006, unfortunately I no longer maintain my library. Feel free to fork it and modify it if you like.